# user-defined conversion to interface

Tags: c#

I just ran into the "user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed" problem in C#.  What I was attempting to do was create a generic Graph class that could be iterated over in a couple different ways, depending on the supported interface.  So:

```
public class Graph<T> : IBreadthFirstSearchTree<T>, IDepthFirstSearchTree<T>
{
    // unnecessary details

    public static explicit operator IBreadthFirstSearchTree<T>(Graph<T> g)
    {
        g.enumerator = new GraphEnumerator<T>(g, SortStrategy.BreadthFirst);
        return g as IBreadthFirstSearchTree<T>;
    }

    public static explicit operator IDepthFirstSearchTree<T>(Graph<T> g)
    {
        g.enumerator = new GraphEnumerator<T>(g, SortStrategy.DepthFirst);
        return g as IDepthFirstSearchTree<T>;
    }
}
```

was intended for this use:

```
foreach (GraphNode<T> gn in myGraph as IDepthFirstSearchTree)
{
    // do stuff with gn
}
```

Anyone know how I can achieve the same syntactic results within the constraints of the language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make your implementations of `IDepthFirstSearchTree<T>` and `IBreadthFirstSearchTree<T>` explicit implementations. That way the members won't be available to be called directly on an expression of type `Graph<T>`, but using "as" (or a cast) the appropriate members will be available.

I'm not sure that's what I'd really do though - I'd probably get rid of the interfaces entirely and have:

```
public IEnumerable<T> IterateBreadthFirst() { ... }
public IEnumerable<T> IterateDepthFirst() { ... }
```

Comment: I agree, I don't like your use of interfaces - its not really what theyre intended for

Comment: It's the resulting syntax I was after.  I really, really like being able to say `foreach (node in mygraph as depthfirstsearchtree)`

Comment: Is this code just hobby code for you alone? If so, that's fine. Otherwise, be aware that it's unidiomatic C# and other developers may well be confused.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to write a GetSearchTree method of some kind anyway, because even if the explicit conversions worked, there wouldn't be a good way to control where in the graph the tree is rooted.