# Why isn't it possible to define implicit cast operator from interface to class?

Tags: c#, interface, implicit-conversion

Say, I have an interface

```
public interface ISomeControl
{
    Control MyControl { get; }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to define something like this:

```
public static implicit operator Control(ISomeControl ctrl)
{
    return ctrl.MyControl;
}
```

Or rather why can't I do that in C#?

Comment: @leppie What am I missing? Why is this approach absolutely wrong?

Comment: For starters an interface cannot have any implementation so you have nowhere to define that operator

Comment: I have no idea why :) You will to summon @ericlippert for that answer :)

Comment: IIRC, the CLR will allow to make such code, just not C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use interface with explicit operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433204/why-cant-i-use-interface-with-explicit-operator)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What if you had a subclass of `Control`, and that subclass implemented the `ISomeControl` interface.

```
class SomeControl : Control, ISomeControl {}
```

Now a cast would be ambiguous -- the built-in upcast, and your user-defined conversion.  So you can't provide user-defined conversions for interfaces.

Comment: I can understand that allowing conversions from an interface to a class type would be ambiguous, but I don't see the ambiguity if a class defines a conversion operator from an interface to itself.  If there exists a conversion from `BaseType` to `Foo`, a class `DerivedType` may also define a conversion to `Foo` without creating ambiguity.  If a class doesn't implement a particular interface but a subclass does, casting a base-type reference to that interface should use the user-defined conversion (regardless of whether the referenced object implements the interface)...

Comment: ...while using a derived-class reference should use the conversion which is statically defined for the derived class.  Even in the case of `Foo<T> : ISomething<T>` specifying a conversion to `ISomething<Int32>` I don't see interfaces as posing any "problem" that classes wouldn't.

Comment: @supercat: `Foo<T> : ISomething<T>` isn't allowed to define a conversion to `ISomething<Int32>` (per the rules quoted by Roland).  And the rationale is that if `T` is `Int32` there would be conflicting conversions.  And no, casting a base class can't use the user-defined conversion, because a base class variable may hold a handle to a derived class instance that implements the interface, and it is required that casting an instance to an interface it implements always uses the built-in (cross-cast) pointer adjustment (it's not a conversion, it doesn't create a new object).

Comment: @BenVoigt: How is that situation different from `Derived<T> : Base<T>` with conversion operator from `Derived<T>` to `Base<string>`?  The conversion operator is applied when trying to store to a `Base<string>` something that the compiler can tell is a type `Derived<T>` for some T, but can't tell that it's a `Derived<string>`.  The idea that a cast to an interface is reference-preserving may happen to be true if the thing being cast is a reference type because of the lack of any other way to perform the cast, but a cast of a value type to an interface type is not...

Comment: ...reference-preserving, and the cast of an unconstrained generic to a reference type may or may not be reference-preserving.  Actually, there are many situations with generics where a user-defined conversion operator may be invoked to cast an object to what happens to be its own type, without complaint.  The rules of what things are, or are not, ambiguous are weird.  I find it strange, for example, that if Foo defines a widening conversion to Bar, and Bar defines a widening conversion from Foo, neither conversion will work because of "ambiguity".  Why not declare that "conversion from" wins?

Comment: @supercat: Why declare that "conversion from" wins?  That's likely to confuse approximately half of programmers who write code with ambiguous conversions.  When something is that easy to fix, a warning or error is the best approach, because it lets the developer control the behavior, and prevents silent misbehavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: In most cases, the implementations of the conversions would be identical, and one could strongly advise against writing code which relied upon the compiler to favor a particular one.  The reason I would favor "conversion from" is that if one derives a new class and allow other things to be converted to it, it would generally make more sense to put all the required conversion operators in the new type (as "conversions from" other types), than to add code to each type from which the thing could be converted.  "Conversion to" is generally a fallback when conversion from isn't workable.

Comment: @supercat: You talk about a "new type", but in order for conversions to exist in both types and each be aware of the other type, it's hard to say one type is newer than the other.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that.

C# specification says:

> ***6.4.1 Permitted user-defined conversions***
>
> C# permits only certain user-defined conversions to be declared. In
>   particular, it is not possible to redefine an already existing
>   implicit or explicit conversion. For a given source type S and target
>   type T, if S or T are nullable types, let S0 and T0 refer to their
>   underlying types, otherwise S0 and T0 are equal to S and T
>   respectively. A class or struct is permitted to declare a conversion
>   from a source type S to a target type T only if all of the following
>   are true:
>
> - S0 and T0 are different types.
> - Either S0 or T0 is the class or struct type in which the operator declaration takes place.
> - Neither S0 nor T0 is an interface-type.
> - Excluding user-defined conversions, a conversion does not exist from S to T or from T to S.

One way you can do it is to have a static method.

```
public class Control
    {
        public static Control FromISomeControl(ISomeControl ctrl)
        {
            return ctrl.MyControl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't address "why?".  Besides, I think he's talking about the Microsoft-provided `Control` class, so you can't add to it.

Comment: I don't know if this is the Framework Control class. I thought it is only an example.

Comment: `Control` is *the Microsoft-provided* class