# Cast KeyValuePair to Interface

Tags: c#, list, casting

I'm having a problem of `InvalidCastException` trying to cast an

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> x
```

to an

```
IList<IItem> y
```

where IItem is my interface
I have tried...

```
IList<IItem> y = (IItem) x; //INVALIDCASTEXCEPTION

IList<IItem> y = x.Cast<IItem>().ToList(); //another exception
```

... someone can help me?

Comment: What is "_another exception_"? Never heard of it. You should also show your interface and a class that implements it.

Comment: What type is `IItem`? Can you show the definition?

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is not `IItem`, what would you expect your cast to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `KeyValuePar<string,object>` cannot be casted to your interface. You need to create instances of a class which implements it, then you can cast it to the interface type.

Assuming this is your interface and a class which implements it:

```
interface IItem
{
    string Prop1 { get; set; }
    object Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class SomeClass : IItem
{
    public string Prop1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Prop2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now you can create a `IList<IItem>` from your `List<KeyValuePar<string,object>>`:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> xList = ...;
IList<IItem> y = xList
    .Select(x => (IItem)new SomeClass { Prop1 = x.Key, Prop2 = x.Value })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` doesn't implement `IItem`, which doesn't seem to be even part of the .NET Framework. You can't cast it, unless you've redefined `KeyValuePair` somewhere.

EDIT: even if you had your interface defined, you couldn't cast an `IList<YourKeyValuePair>` to `IList<IItem>` because `IList` is not covariant. You could cast it to an `IEnumerable<IItem>`, however.

Answer (score -1):

You could define a cast to `IItem` yourself using the [explicit keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or the [implicit keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: No IItem is an interface - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433204/why-cant-i-use-interface-with-explicit-operator

Comment: The `implicit` operator is purely a compile time construct.  The `Cast` method will not take user defined implicit conversions into account.