# Implicit conversion doesn't work for IReadOnlyCollection

Tags: c#, .net-core, implicit-conversion

Here's my code:

```cs
public readonly struct Either<TLeft, TRight>
{
    public TLeft? Left { get; } = default;
    public TRight? Right { get; } = default;

    public static implicit operator Either<TLeft, TRight>(TLeft left) => new(left);
    public static implicit operator Either<TLeft, TRight>(TRight right) => new(right);

    private Either(TLeft left) => Left = left;
    private Either(TRight right) => Right = right;
}

public record SomeType(Either<IReadOnlyCollection<int>, int> Something);

public class Class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<int> test1 = new[] { 1, 2 };
        int[] test2 = new[] { 1, 2 };

        var d1 = new SomeType(test1);  // FAILS
        var d2 = new SomeType(test2);  // OK
    }
}
```

I have the `Either` type, which contains implicit conversions to simplify its creation.
There's also `SomeType`, which expects `Either<IReadOnlyCollection<int>, int>` in its constructor. Variables `d1` and `d2` are two examples of how I'm trying to utilize the implicit conversion. For some reason, `d2` works just fine, while `d1` has a compilation error:

> Argument type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection' is not assignable to parameter type 'EitherExperiments.Either<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection,int>'

What's wrong? `test1` is of exactly the same type that `Either` contains in its `Left` wing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [user-defined conversion to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308986/user-defined-conversion-to-interface)

Comment: The problem is not the type itself, but the fact that `test1` is an interface, and the language doesn't permit implicit conversion from/to an interface.

Comment: @IanKemp Thanks, now I get it. However, your last comment is much clearer to me than the linked question.